# Unique column in many to many association doctrine 2

Tags: postgresql, doctrine-orm

I used One-To-Many, Unidirectional with Join Table association as in documentation in yaml but in database unique constraint was not created.

I m using postgres. What am I doing wrong?

This is my entity that has two "One-To-Many, Unidirectional with Join Table" association "questions" and "answers"

```
TestCasesPersistence\Entities\GroupQA:
    type: entity
    table: group_qa
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            nullable: false
            length: null
            fixed: false
            id: true
            column: id
            generator:
                strategy: IDENTITY
    fields:
        name:
            type: string
            nullable: true
            length: null
            fixed: false
            column: name
        timeCreated:
            type: datetime
            nullable: true
            column: time_created
    manyToMany:
        questions:
            targetEntity: Question
            joinTable:
                name: group_qa_questions
            joinColumns:
                group_qa_id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
            inverseJoinColumns:
                question_id:
                    unique: true
                    referencedColumnName: id
        answers:
            targetEntity: Answer
            joinTable:
                name: group_qa_answers
            joinColumns:
                group_qa_id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
            inverseJoinColumns:
                answer_id:
                    unique: true
                    referencedColumnName: id
        typeSearches:
            targetEntity: TypeSearch
            joinTable:
                name: group_qa_type_searches
            joinColumns:
                group_qa_id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
            inverseJoinColumns:
                type_search_id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Documentation http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html

Section 5.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a bug in yaml configs of "answers" and "questions" assosiations

Correct way:

```
manyToMany:
    questions:
        targetEntity: Question
        joinTable:
            name: group_qa_questions
            joinColumns:
               group_qa_id:
                  referencedColumnName: id
            inverseJoinColumns:
               question_id:
                  unique: true
                  referencedColumnName: id
    answers:
        targetEntity: Answer
        joinTable:
           name: group_qa_answers
           joinColumns:
              group_qa_id:
                 referencedColumnName: id
           inverseJoinColumns:
              answer_id:
                 unique: true
                 referencedColumnName: id
```